# Added JAVA_HOME in environment var but tomcat says it can't see it

Tags: java, environment-variables

I just want to try a software which uses tomcat. I added JAVA_HOME to env variables for user and for system on windows 7. I checked several times it has been saved.

When I run startup it says neither JAVA_HOME nor JRE_HOME is defined. At least one of these is needed.

Indeed when I type set under cmd, I can't see JAVA_HOME in the list, why since I added in environment panel ?

Comment: You have to close all open command prompt windows and then open a new one to get the environment variable edit to take effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you started a new command prompt since you defined the environment variable? The windows command prompt inherits its environment at startup.